# Want to Add three new fields with add more button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, css

I am working on one php, booststrap script that collect website address. By default there is one single field that can collect website name that are linked to address1 in the my sql. I have two more values add in mysql called address2, address3.

I want to add a Add more button under the address1 field so users can click on them and add another website if they have. Here is the code that i am using:

```
             <div class="span12">
             <form class="form-horizontal" id="registerHere" method='post' action=''>
  <fieldset>

<div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="input01">Website Address 1</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="address1" name="address1">

      </div>
</div>

       <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="input01">Website Address 2</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="address2" name="address2">

      </div>
         </div> 

        <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="input01">Website Address 3</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="address3" name="address3">

      </div>
          </div>    
          </div>
```

As you seen in the above code i want to hide Website Address 2 and website address 3 field hidden but show when click on add more button that i want to put under Website Address 1. I am in hurry so please guide me. Please don't forget to limit only for 2 more fields i don't want someone click on again and again that result lots of new fields.

Thanks

Demo Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOm7d.png

Answer (score 4):

You can show the next address field when the one before it is focused like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/KfQbb/

```
var $group = $('.control-group');

$group.hide().first().show();

$group.on('focus', 'input', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.control-group').next('.control-group').slideDown();
});
```

And here is a version using an Add More button: http://jsfiddle.net/KfQbb/4/

```
var $group = $('.control-group');

$group.hide().first().show();

$group.on('click', '.more', function(e) {
    var $next = $(this).closest('.control-group').next('.control-group').slideDown();
    $(e.currentTarget).hide();    
    if ($next.find('.more').hasClass('last')) {
        $next.find('.more').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have lots of other fields too in the same form like address, city, location using your code all fields doing same :D so this will not work for me.

Comment: Both examples limit the number of fields to display to 2 only. Go to the fiddle link if you want the complete code.

Comment: Your codes works in well in http://jsfiddle.net/linksdigger/DP26U/5/ using jquery 1.11.0. I add it in header also                                        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>                


<script type="text/javascript">
your code here 
</script>

but it want onload option to work in my running php script how i can onload. Please tell me. In the http://jsfiddle.net/linksdigger/DP26U/5/ you can see i have selected onload. Please tell me about this. Thanks

Comment: That's a different issue; please post a new question